# What are the side effects of using a large max_gram for an nGram tokenizer in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to understand the implications of using a large setting for max_gram when using the nGram tokenizer. I know it will explode the size of the index, but then what? Will it make searches slower? will it cause things to error out? etc

Comment: Hi, I also have same doubt, How much memory it occupies if we use nGram max_gram as 100000 or more, will it make search Slow? will it occupy more memory in every node? please clarify somebody about this.... 
           Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1):

It'll make searches slower for sure, because lots of tokens will be generated for comparison.

In general, you should analyze your business and find out what size of ngram is suitable for your field.
Ex: for a product ID, you can support search ngram for max 20 chars (max_gram=20), because usually people only remember 5 or 6 chars of a product ID, 20 is good enough.